# emacs + clojure + find definition of function

Tags: emacs, clojure

### Problem Statement:

I am writing Clojure (and some ClojureScript) code with Lein + Emacs.

I want to be able to jump to the definition of an arbitrary function.

For example, suppose I do "C-x magic-key-stroke rect->area", then I want it to jump me to:

```
src/rect.clj, line 20, which has the content:
  (defn rect->area [] ... )
```

### Question:

How do I achieve the above in Emacs / Clojure?

### Edit:

I sorta lied in my original question. I'm not using clj + cljs.

I'm using cljx (https://github.com/lynaghk/cljx) , which does cljx -> clj/cljs.

As a result, a "nrepl" solution does not work as well as something that reads the source code. (I.e. I want it to jump me to the *.cljx file, not the *.clj file).

Answer (score 5):

If you scroll to the bottom [here](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/emacs.html) you'll see this:

> If instead you want to jump to the source of the function you can use M-., which is awesome. This works on your own functions as well as those which come from third-party libraries. Use M-, to pop the stack and return to where you were.

Does this help?

Comment: Note than you need running nrepl connection for `M-.` to work

Comment: EDIT: I'm using cljx, which I failed to mention in my original question. Thus M-. ends up hitting the generated file, not the source file.

Comment: @user1985576 I write Clojure using IntellijIDEA and the CursiveClojure plugin (previously using LaClojure). If you check out the CursiveClojure site, http://cursiveclojure.com/ , you'll se that you can emulate an Emacs environment, but all I need to do to immediately jump to the source of any function is a mouse click while holding Ctrl.

Comment: Cursive looks awesome, and was tempted to switching a while back. However, I'm not ready to make the jump yet, and am looking for a pure-emacs solution.

Comment: @edbond why it need a running nrepl ?

Comment: @JiacaiLiu because repl will index sources not emacs. See https://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/images/cider_architecture.png and a link mentioned in answer.